# my user_id profile database is null, how i insert the value in user_id?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mysql

[image]

Why does my data look like this?

can i make the value in user_id?
if i delete the def create_user_profile it will create nama, nik, email, nomor_hp.
but user_id is null

in the picture, id 1 and 2 i created without def create_user_profile
and id 3,4,5,6 is created when i user def create_user_profile

this is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    nomor_hp = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

this is my views.py to create a user, did i made a mistake here?

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            profile.save()
            uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            domain = get_current_site(request).domain
            link=reverse('activate', kwargs={
                        'uidb64': uidb64, 'token': token_generator.make_token(user)})
            activate_url = 'http://'+domain+link
            email_body = 'Hallo '+user.username + 'Tolong gunakan link ini untuk verifikasi akun anda\n' +activate_url
            email_subject = 'Aktivasi Akun Anda'
            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                email_body,
                'noreply@kantorkecamatanbintanutara.com',
                [profile.email],
            )
            email.send(fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('/pengurusan/signin')
        else:
            return render(request, 'pengurusan/register.html', {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form
            })
```

Comment: It looks like you are creating other `Profile` objects somewhere else than in the trigger, and that these views/signals/... create a `Profile` without a `User`.

Comment: if i delete the signal, value user_id will not appear at all

Comment: how to solved that problem? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but the signal is likely not responsible for the records with a missing `user_id`. Likely it is some *other* view/signal that creates these records.

Comment: i already add my views in there, did i made a mistake there? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: you should not both create a `Profile` in the signals, and one in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `signup` view and the signal makes a `Profile` object, and to make matters even worse, in the latter you do not link to the user.

I advise to drop the signal that creates the `Profile`. It has not much use. If you later edit the `Profile`, you should simply safe it, furthermore you should ensure that when you create a `User` object, you simply link it properly. For example with:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            profile_form.instance.user = user
            profile = profile_form.save()
            # …
    # …
```

Comment: thanks you for the explanation, advice and help, its works